# Recuperar Model de Usuarios eliminado en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Siguiendo un tutorial de CRUD con Laravel y VUE, en un momento me hace borrar el Model 'User.php' porque no íbamos a utilizarlo. Pero ahora me encuentro con que quiero usarlo porque quiero hacer un sistema de aravel. Quise re-crear el model con "php artisan make:model User -m" pero me dice que el Modelo ya existe ( cuando en la Carpeta 'App' no existe, ya que lo he eliminado )

¿Hay alguna forma de recuperar ese Modelo, o me toca hacer una aplicación Laravel de 0 nuevamente?

Comment: reinicia tu servidor  y vuelve intentar

Comment: ¿Cuál servidor? No utilizo el php artisan serve

Comment: o mas bien reinicia  php

Comment: El tema es que php no tiene nada que ver porque es un problema de los archivos de Laravel. Creo que me toca crear una nueva aplicación de 0 y pasar todas las cosas que tengo ya hechas.

Comment: Error mio. Estaba ejecutando el comando en otra aplicación Laravel. Ya pude ejecutar el comando correctamente!